# Find what URL an EXE file is sending data to

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring, url

How can I monitor an EXE file when it is running to see what URL it is connecting to?  I assume there must be free software out there that can do this fairly easily?

Comment: Any firewall that monitors outgoing traffic should tell you. Set the firewall running, then start the program. It's request should be logged and then you can find the URL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For in depth analysis, Wireshark is your best bet as Phoshi has already mentioned. For a quick look at the URL, you can use `netstat` from the command line, or [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx).

[image]

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>netstat -b

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    john:1969              85.65.97.58.dynamic.barak-online.net:27645
  [deluged.exe]

  TCP    john:1604              vx-in-f100.1e100.net:http  ESTABLISHED  2904
  [firefox.exe]

  TCP    john:1716              79-114-229-43:60126  ESTABLISHED        732
  [deluged.exe]
```

Comment: +1 didn't know about console netstat

Answer (score 9):

Try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - it's just about the best out there.

Comment: +1 for Wireshark as well :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the "URL" part, [SmartSniff](http://nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) is one of the easiest tools. It can be used as a generic packet sniffer too.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I believe you can also find this out with `netstat` command. But I don't know for sure anymore because I am not running windows(only when really necessary) anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/). It's a proxy for doze, which registers itself as the system proxy. If your application uses the system proxy (it might bypass it) then its requests will be intercepted by Fiddler when it's running.