# Can I use Wireshark to see what URLs my computer is invoking?

Tags: http, wireshark

Is it possible to use Wireshark to see what URL and what params are being requested by my computer?

Something like:

```
www.foobar.com/someendpoint/bazboo
```

Does Wireshark offer this information in its package capture information?

I downloaded Fiddler2, but it did not show any new request being made while I interacted with this application in question. I'm sure it's doing online requests and not loading data from local cache.

Would Wireshark show me this URL being invoked?

Comment: Put simply. Yes.

Comment: The URLs would appear in the data of unencrypted DNS requests. You would have to correlate the IP addresses returned for those requests. It's possible the app is using hard-coded IP addresses, in which case there would not necessarily be any URLs used.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Wireshark will show ALL network traffic over a network including URLs, unencrypted passwords, etc.

Comment: could be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/100865/find-what-url-an-exe-file-is-sending-data-to

Comment: Unless the connection is secured, in which case Wireshark can only show the raw TCP packets.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question, the other question was vague. This question specifically asks about Wireshark.